# Intent.ACTION_CALL not working only in android 9 pie

Tags: android, android-intent

I have given ACTION_CALL permisiion on menifest file also but in android 9 pie it is not working..IT is also working in android 10

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:100"));
                                    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: what says logcat?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have set permission in the manifest 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>`
Then try this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + xxxxxxxx));
startActivity(intent);
```

if you want to do it without any permission simply use `ACTION_DIAL` instead of `ACTION_CALL` to pre-populate the dialer and let the user make the call

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:xxxxxxx"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

ADD Permission in the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Add Intent

```
int number = 123 123 123
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
startActivity(i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));)
```